# Ruby on Rails vs HTML CSS and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, ruby-on-rails

Iam new to this but I am wondering how is Rails different from  just regularly putting in the HTML CSS and JavaScript into notepad or something in creating a website? Because all it seems to me is you are doing a little extra side steps into setting everything up and putting things into different folders with Rails and everything is bunched together I guess visually to me regular notepad is easier to look at but can someone please explain thanks!

Comment: Rails is for building dynamic web applications. Just creating static HTML files in notepad will just give you static web pages with no user interaction.  Totally different things. Its like asking "why have a toolbox when you can do everything with a hammer?".

Answer (score 2):

Ruby on Rails is a web application MVC framework. It is considered server side and it is used to query the server data, etc. It serves as the back end for the web application, whereas HTML, CSS, Javascript are front end.

Here is the difference between front end and back end from Wikipedia:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_and_back_ends.

Rails is a MVC framework which stands for Model, View, Controller where View is where your HTML, CSS and Javascript will be. It has the extra functionality (but not limited to) where the controller is responsible for responding to user input and perform interactions on the data model objects and where models manages the data.